# Problema con 'La conversión especificada no es válida'

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy intentando de extraer ciertos datos de una tabla, necesito extraer los datos específicos de las celdas CdgoTrcro y Horas, además de eso requiero que si por ejemplo tengo múltiples veces un CdgoTrcro  entonces me haga la sumatoria de horas de todas las veces que se muestre ese CdgoTrcro y me muestre en otro formulario los CdgoTrcro  y las horas totales que tiene c/u, hasta ahora he estado intentandolo de esta forma pero me muestra un error:

````
DataTable resultadosTable = new DataTable(); 
resultadosTable.Columns.Add("Código de Tercero", typeof(int)); resultadosTable.Columns.Add("Total de Horas", typeof(int));      


// Obtiene dinámicamente los códigos de tercero de ultraGrid1.
        var codigosDeTercero = ultraGrid1.Rows
            .Select(row => (int)row.Cells["CdgoTrcro"].Value)
            .Distinct();

        bool hayDatos = false; // Variable para verificar si hay al menos un dato en la tabla

        // Realiza la suma de horas por cada código de tercero y agrega los resultados a la tabla
        foreach (var codigo in codigosDeTercero)
        {
            // Filtra las filas con el código actual y que tengan un valor numérico en la celda "Horas"
            var filasConCodigo = ultraGrid1.Rows
                .Where(row =>
                    row.Cells["CdgoTrcro"].Value != DBNull.Value &&
                    Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["CdgoTrcro"].Value) == codigo &&
                    row.Cells["Horas"].Value != null &&
                    IsNumeric(row.Cells["Horas"].Value))
                .ToList();

            // Verifica si hay datos en las filas antes de realizar la suma
            if (filasConCodigo.Any())
            {
                // Realiza la suma de las horas, manejando DBNull.Value
                var totalHoras = filasConCodigo
                    .Sum(row => IsNumeric(row.Cells["Horas"].Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Horas"].Value) : 0);

                // Agrega el resultado a la tabla
                resultadosTable.Rows.Add(codigo, totalHoras);

                hayDatos = true; // Hay al menos un dato en la tabla
            }
            else
            {
                // Muestra un mensaje de error si no hay datos para el código actual
                MessageBox.Show($"No hay datos válidos para el código de tercero {codigo}.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        // Muestra el formulario FrmDistribucion solo si hay datos
        if (hayDatos)
        {
            FrmDistribucion frmDistribucion = new FrmDistribucion();
            frmDistribucion.ResultadosTable = resultadosTable;
            frmDistribucion.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            // Muestra un mensaje de error si no hay datos en la tabla
            MessageBox.Show("No hay datos para mostrar.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    // Función para verificar si un objeto es numérico
    private bool IsNumeric(object value)
    {
        return value is int || value is float || value is double || value is decimal;
    } ```
````

Comment: Hola Diego podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron útiles y de haberlo sido marcar como aceptada la que más útil te haya sido, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Sin entender muy bien lo que quieres hacer, cuando recorres la colección codigosDeTercero, ¿por qué vuelves a filtrar por la lista ultraGrid1.Rows? la colección codigosDeTercero viene de ultraGrid1.Rows filtrada.

Analizando un poco más en profundidad tu código, entiendo que puedes tener varias rows con el mismo código y quieres sumar las horas correspondientes a un mismo código. Lo que tienes que hacer es agrupar por código y sumar las horas

```
var codigosDeTercero = ultraGrid1.Rows
    .Where(x => CumpleCondicionUsuario())
    .AsParallel()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Cells["CdgoTrcro"].Value)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Codigo = g.Key ?? "N/A",
        SumaHoras = g.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Horas"].Value) ?? 0)
    });

// Puedes mostrar los resultados de alguna manera, como en la consola o en otro control
foreach (var resultado in codigosDeTercero)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Código: {resultado.Codigo}, Suma de Horas: {resultado.SumaHoras}");
}

private bool CumpleCondicionUsuario()
{
    bool resultadoCondicioUsuario = false;

    // TuCódigoPorElQueFiltraElUsuario

    retun resultadoCondicioUsuario 
}
```

He forzado el SumaHoras cuando un código es nulo (DBNull). En tal caso la suma será 0.

Dime si la solución propuesta te sirve.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, realmente fue de mucha ayuda, sin embargo me da es la sumatoria total de la tabla y requiero es la de los datos que filtre el usuario, ya que inicialmente el usuario primero hace una serie de filtros en la tabla y la idea es capturar o extraer la sumatoria de las horas de esos CdgoTrcro que se encuentren en la tabla en ese momento.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para que veas como filtrar las rows de tu DataGrid.

Se debe de aplicar un Where(...) a ultraGrid1.Rows.

Si mi respuesta te sirve de ayudar, valorala, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Vayamos por parte para que entiendas bien. Lo primero que se hace es una consulta **Linq**, la cual nos va a devolver una lista, donde cada elemento de esa lista sería un **objeto anónimo** con dos propiedades: **Codigo** y **Horas**:

```
var lista = from r in ultraGrid.Rows
            select new
            {
                Codigo = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["CdgoTrcro"].Value,
                Horas = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["Horas"].Value
            };
```

Después haremos lo siguiente:

```
var listaFinal = (from l in lista
                  group l by l.Codigo into grupo 
                  select new 
                  {
                      Codigo = grupo.Key,
                      TotalHoras = grupo.Sum(h => h.Horas)
                  }).ToList();
```

Lo que se hace aquí es utilizar nuevamente **Linq** y se agrupa por el código, obteniendo de esta forma el total de horas para este código.

Finalmente harías:

```
ultraGrid.DataSource = listaFinal;
```

De esta forma enlazamos el resultado obtenido al **DataGridView**.

Para hacer uso de **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```